# "Drop Over" a higher channel in Video Sequence Editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Let's say I want to edit a video made of with 50 strips which replace each other with some fading between each strip. Because two consecutive strips will overlap, I put each next strip in a higher channel, use "Over Drop" and opacity (from 0. to 1., or the reverse) with keyframes, and it works fine. But Blender is limited to 32 channels and I do not know how to include the 33th strip. I guess it is possible to put it in channel 1 and not use "Over Drop", maybe "Alpha Under" or something? What should I do? What is the best practice?

Comment: This is true if you are fade-ing the next strip over the last. Don't forget that you can also fade 'out' the previous strip as well, allowing you to place the next strip 'under' the first. No stacking problem then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is only 3 channels needed to make unlimited count of fades. Use Cross or Gamma Cross for creating fade effect:

[image]

And you don't need to use keyframes in this case, fade effect will be from start of one strip to end from other strip.

[image]

And channel position doesn't matter, first and second strip sets up not by top and bottom order, but by selection: first and second selected.

[image]